# Maximum likelihood: closed form or not? How to determine?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

There are a lot of problems that are solved by Maximum likelihood method. How to determine if the problem has a closed-form solution or not?

Comment: By trying? seeing?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I suppose the question's really how to distinguish between its not having one & your not having tried hard enough.

Comment: This strikes me as more of a general mathematical question, rather than anything statistics-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a rule here but in general this can be determined from the First Order conditions. If you end up having to solve non-linear equations, which cannot be simplified, then a numerical procedure is the way to proceed.